# Init action and refresh page after form action

Tags: functions, actions, forms, init, row-actions

My problem is that I can't refresh the page after a form action into a loop. 
In my case I have a listing post page where I can delete, archive, deliver posts through a **modal form**, row by row.

After asking a previous question [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/229139/refresh-page-after-form-action) I've known that I should perform the form action through the `init` hook to make it run before headers are sent.

I've tried without success like this:
In my functions.php

```
add_action('init', 'init_deliver'); //trying to run it before headers
function init_deliver($pid){
    //code to archive the post
    //update_post_meta etc...
}
add_action('deliver_post', 'delivered_action');
function delivered_action($pid) { 
    if(isset($_POST['deliver']))
    {   
        init_deliver($pid); //calling a the init function
    } ?>
 <div id="modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
     <form method="post"> 
        <input id="deliver" type="submit" name="deliver" class="submit_green" style="width:100%; text-align:center;" />
     </form>
 </div>
}
```

And I call all this in my loop like this

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#-modal">Deliver?</a>
<?php do_action("deliver_post", $pid); ?> <!--I pass here the post id $pid-->
```

The post is delivered but the page doesn't refresh when I submit the form. It refreshes always the second time I reload it.
I need instead that the page is immediately refreshed after form submitting. Can you please give me **an example** or drive me through it? Thanks.

Comment: Why not wrap the code from `init` in `if(isset($_POST['deliver']))` conditional? You can access all form data (`$_POST` here) from `init` or `wp` hook, in case some WordPress objects and functions don't work on `init` then switch to `wp`..

Comment: The problem is that I'm in the loop and when $_POST is submitted the page doesn't refresh. I need to run the deliver before the loop.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/init/

```
add_action( 'init', 'process_post' );
 
function process_post() {
     if( isset( $_POST['unique_hidden_field'] ) ) {
          // process $_POST data here
     }
}
```

In your example, perhaps having two different `add_action` is causing problems and burying your function where it's not firing during `init`

I'm going to test a similar solution and see what happens, I will update if I learn more.

Comment: Detailed solution I found: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29232764/how-to-properly-url-redirect-in-wordpress-after-form-submission